# How to reset Canon 70D WiFi?

Tags: canon-70d, wifi

When I go to the WiFi Settings in Camera (Canon 70D) all I see is:

Connection:

- Exit
- Confirm Set
- Error Details *(greyed out)*

I can't recall the password or find any way to reset it. Some I found ([Why doesn't wifi on canon 70D connect to my Android device?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/why-doesnt-wifi-on-canon-70d-connect-to-my-android-device)) say the Camera should say Infrastructure mode. Inside the Confirm Settings I can see on page 3 it shows:

> Connect'n method: Camera access point mode

But again I see no way to change this.

On my Smartphone EOS Remote app there's a Connection Guide with completely different menus from what I'm seeing on the Camera.

Any idea how I can reset the WiFi Name and Password on the Canon 70D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this answer up with the times, I want to let people know that Canon released a new version of their app called 'Camera Connect'. Once you download it, you'll need to reset your wireless settings on your camera and your phone. There is a different handshake that occurs between your phone and the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had to reset my phone’s settings, so I lost my connection to my camera. I was perplexed trying to find the password. Finally I found how to reset the Wi-Fi and then be given a new password.

Select Wi-Fi function > And then on the ‘Connection’ screen, select Exit. Don’t just *exit* the screen by hitting menu or *back*. Actually select Exit on the touchscreen or highlight Exit with the directional buttons and press the *enter* button.

On ‘Exit wireless LAN function’ screen, select Ok.

Now press the ‘Info’ button to enter General settings. (Or make selection on screen.)

Now you can choose ‘Clear Wi-Fi settings’ , select Ok.

Once you do that you can then select ‘Wi-Fi function’ again, select ‘Connect to smartphone’, and follow the prompts to create a new “camera Wi-Fi”, in which you can then be given the password during the creation process.

Whew! That was driving me nuts!

Let me know if that works for anyone else!

Comment: Worked well on a recently purchased 70D with all previous owners settings! Thanks for saving me a lot of grief!

Answer (score 1):

So I had to hit Exit to get back to a main menu, strange.

And for the second part EOS Remote is no longer in use or functioning. Had to download Canon Connect onto my Smartphone instead.